# React js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem (
There are my components:

```
class Main extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            total: 0
        };
        this.totalFuns = this.totalFuns.bind(this);
    }

    totalFuns(event){

        this.setState({total: event})
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <main>
                <Item data_items={data} data_cnt={this.totalFuns} />
            </main>
        );
    }
}

export default Main;
```

then Item component:

```
class Item extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.skuChange = this.skuChange.bind(this);
    }

    skuChange(event) {

        this.props.data_cnt(event)

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <section className="item" data-index={this.props.data_index}>
                <Select values={this.props.data_items} onChange={this.skuChange}/>
            </section>
        );
    }
}

export default Item;
```

then Select component

```
class Select extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
        this.setState({value: event.target.label});
    }

    render() {

        var options = this.props.values;

        var options_list = options.map(function(obj,i){

            return (
                <option value={i} key={i} label={obj.label} />
            )
        });

        return (
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {options_list}
            </select>

        );
    }
}

export default Select;
```

In console show: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'totalFuns' of undefined. Without this fun my app work correct.. (

Why?

Answer (score 0):

Your function is actually called `totalFuns` but you have `totalFun`.

So this line:

`<Item data_items={data} data_cnt={this.totalFun} />`

should be

`<Item data_items={data} data_cnt={this.totalFuns} />`

Comment: sorry.. it's my mystake in this answer.. In my code is all good.. everywhere totalFuns

Comment: ..and console error: Cannot read property 'totalFuns' of undefined

Comment: What line is it referencing that is causing that error?

Comment: Could you put your code in a CodePen or a snipet ? It will be easier to help you

Answer (score 0):

In your Select component, the state `value` was initially undefined and hence you were getting error. Also, the options can be selected based on value instead of label. See the working snippet below. Also I do not see data being present in the `Main` component

```js
class Main extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            total: 0
        };
        this.totalFuns = this.totalFuns.bind(this);
    }

    totalFuns(event){
        console.log(event);
        this.setState({total: event})
    }

    render() {
        var data = [{label: 1}, {label: 2}]
        return (
            <main>
                <Item data_items={data} data_cnt={this.totalFuns} />
            </main>
        );
    }
}


class Item extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.skuChange = this.skuChange.bind(this);
    }

    skuChange(event) {

        this.props.data_cnt(event)

    }

    render() {

        return (
            <section className="item" data-index={this.props.data_index}>
                <Select values={this.props.data_items} onChange={this.skuChange}/>
            </section>
        );
    }
}


class Select extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        }
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.props.onChange(event.target.value);
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    render() {

        var options = this.props.values;

        var options_list = options.map(function(obj,i){

            return (
                <option value={obj.label} key={i} label={obj.label} />
            )
        });

        return (
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                {options_list}
            </select>

        );
    }
} 

ReactDOM.render(<Main/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```